# Splitting a string by another string

Tags: c#, string

I got a string which I need to separate by another string which is a substring of the original one. Let's say I got the following text:

```
string s = "<DOC>something here <TEXT> and some stuff here </TEXT></DOC>"
```

And I want to retrieve:

```
"and some stuff here"
```

I need to get the string between the `"<TEXT>"` and his locker `"</TEXT>"`.

I don't manage to do so with the common split method of string even though one of the function parameters is of type `string[]`. What I am trying is :

```
Console.Write(s.Split("<TEXT>")); // Which doesn't compile
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Is the last tag `</TEXT>` or `</DOC>`?

Comment: u are right .... doc i will edit it

Comment: Your example suggests that you are not splitting, but extracting.

Comment: Seems a lot like XML. If it is, load it up in XDocument and do a xpath select on the XML DOM.

Comment: its not XML unfortunatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var start = s.IndexOf("<TEXT>");
var end = s.IndexOf("</TEXT>", start+1);
string res;
if (start >= 0 && end > 0) {
    res = s.Substring(start, end-start-1).Trim();
} else {
    res = "NOT FOUND";
}
```

Comment: The indexOf for end should start the search from the value of `start`.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on "`<TEXT>`" isn't going to help you in this case anyway, since the close tag is "`</TEXT>`".

The most robust solution would be to parse it properly as XML. C# provides functionality for doing that. The second example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx should put you on the right track.

However, if you're just looking for a quick-and-dirty one-time solution your best bet is going to be to hand-code something, such as dasblinkenlight's solution above.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "<DOC>something here <TEXT> and some stuff here </TEXT></DOC>";
string result = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=<TEXT>).*?(?=</TEXT>)").Value;
```

EDIT: I am using this regex pattern `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)` which will match a position between a prefix and a suffix.

EDIT 2:
Find several results:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, "(?<=<TEXT>).*?(?=</TEXT>)");
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: i will need to get acouple of reasults is there some sort of way to get alot of reasults in this way ... my string includes alot of <TEXT></TEXT>

Answer (score 1):

```
var output = new List<String>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(source, "<TEXT>(.*?)</TEXT>")) {
    output.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: the output list containst nothing (thanks alot for trying to help)

Answer (score 0):

If last tag is `</doc>` then you could use [`XElement.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435.aspx) to load XML and then go through it to discover wanted element (you could also use Linq To XML).

If this is not necessarily correct XML string, you could always go with `Regural Expressions` to find desired part of text. In this case expression should not be to hard to write it yourself.